# Why does tinypng make pics brighter?

Tags: image, compression, png

I like to compress png images via [tinypng](http://tinypng.com) service. It's saves up to 97% of png-picture size. But sometimes resulting picture looks more brighter than original. And it's bad. The question is why does my image become brighter? An how to avoid this effect?

On tinypng website they write:

```
Because the number of colors is reduced, 24-bit PNG files can be converted to much smaller 8-bit indexed color images. All unnecessary metadata is stripped too.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because tinypng uses Lossy compression it can alter image quality including brightness, if you want there to be no effect on image quality you should look at using lossless compression which only strips out unnecessary metadata and won't affect image quality, you could try using:

- https://kraken.io/web-interface/
- http://www.punypng.com

Comment: Great! Thank you, I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 4):

The recompressed image is brighter because tinypng removes ancillary chunks. I verified that fact by sending it a PNG containing a "gAMA 1.0" chunk.

If the input image has a gAMA chunk, tinypng removes it and the image is displayed as though it were sRGB (gamma=1/2.2).

If the input image has no colorspace chunks (gAMA, sRGB, cHRM, or iCCP), or if it has those but they contain a colorspace that is exactly sRGB or close to sRGB, removing them is pretty safe and won't change the image brightness.

You can avoid the effect by using another application that doesn't remove ancillary chunks, or you can convert your image to the sRGB colorspace before sending them to tinypng.

Or, you could use a PNG editor to restore the gAMA chunk.  There are many PNG editors available.  Personally, I'd use pngsplit to extract the gAMA chunk from the original and to separate the chunks in the tiny PNG, then "cat" the chunks from the compressed file together with the old gAMA chunk (put it right after the IHDR chunk) to form a new compressed file with the right gAMA.